# Нахождение расстояния между двумя наименьшими элементами массива

Tags: java, массивы

Задание такое: "Создать консольное приложение, которое принимало бы на вход ряд чисел и выводило расстояние между двумя наименьшими. Например, дано ряд чисел: "23 45 34 12 45 4 38 56 2 49 100". Наименьшие числа в нем 2 и 4. Расстояние между ними - 3 (имеется ввиду разница между индексами по модулю)"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter random numbers:");
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    int[] mas = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mas[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

    int indexOfMax = mas[0];
    int indexOfMin = mas[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if(mas[i] > indexOfMax)
            indexOfMax = mas[i];

        if(mas[i] <indexOfMin)
            indexOfMin = mas[i];
    }
    System.out.println(indexOfMax+" "+indexOfMin);
}
```

то бишь я заполняю массив значениями с консоли. Решила попробовать найти хотя бы минимальное и максимальное значение.. не получилось. максимальное находится через раз, а минимальное постоянно 0.

как найти 2 минимальных значения массива, введенного с консоли? (не сортирую массив)

Comment: Что, по вашему, означает эта строка?
indexOfMax = mas[i];

Comment: что  indexOfMaх равен і-му элементу массива

Comment: Зачем же вы в названии переменной тогда пишете про индекс, если в ней значение элемента? :-)

Comment: изначально там планировался вывод индекса, но для начала решила попробовать вывести элемент

Comment: Есть у меня подозрение что вы привели не тот код, который выполняете... Пробуйте в отладчике смотреть, почему такое странное поведение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] mas = {23, 45, 34, 12, 45, 4, 38, 56, 2, 49, 100};

    int min1 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int min2 = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
        if( mas[i] < min1) {
            min2 = min1;
            min1 = mas[i];
            index2 = index1;
            index1 = i;
        } else if (mas[i] < min2) {
            min2 = mas[i];
            index2 = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Math.abs(index1 - index2));
}
```

Comment: задача немного отличается: нужно найти индексы массива, заполненного с консоли, а не индексы массива с заданными числами :)

Comment: Ввести числа с консоли это элементарное и я специально это отпустил, ваш код выше с ней должен справляться (надеюсь вы в курсе, что первым числом с консоли у вас кол-во собственно чисел?)

Comment: @DianaMeissen для демонстрации явно удобнее использовать константы. Если вы написали весь код из вопроса, то изменить на чтение из консоли думаю труда не составит.

Comment: теперь в курсе, только вот проблем с вводом с консоли нет. Проблемы с определение минимума из этих введенных чисел

Comment: Я вам написал весь код по определению минимума, он не работает?

Comment: @pavel сейчас попробую

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin ваш код работает идеально, но вот стоит только заменить массив - как выдается чушь

Comment: заменила int[] mas = {23, 45, 34, 12, 45, 4, 38, 56, 2, 49, 100}; на Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter random numbers:");
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    int[] mas = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        mas[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }

когда ввела цифры "9 7 8 4 2 6 5 3 8 7"
выдало 3

Comment: На какой массив вы меняете?

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin на тот который написан в вопросе. На массив с вводом чисел с консоли

Comment: "когда ввела цифры "9 7 8 4 2 6 5 3 8 7" выдало 3" а что вы ожидаете? Минимальные цифры 2 и 3, между их индексами разность 3. Что по вашему должно было выдать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68625/discussion-between-diana-meissen-and-viacheslav-vedenin).